# Express query string check and send to client

Tags: node.js, express

I am currently working on project with express node.js to make web app.

Since I am new to express system and studying.. I need help!

I want to set route with query string and want to check if the query strings are validate to send.

For example, the query string would be like below(Has year, month)

```
https://localhost:3000/?year=2021&month=8
```

In that case, I want to compare the year / month date value is prior to the time of today.
If today is 2021-08-31, then year should be equal or less than 2021 and month should be checked by year value.

If year and month query is not provided, then I want to add it and route to next.

I want to make some several route pages like below. Below is app.js file.

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var aRouter = require('./routes/a');
var bRouter = require('./routes/b');
var cRouter = require('./routes/c');
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', aRouter);
app.use('/b', bRouter);
app.use('/c', cRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

With above code, user can be routed to a, b, c router. Before routed to any url, the query string should be checked first.
How can I do that simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by below reference code.

```
const router = require("express").Router()

router.get("/", (req, res, next) => {

    if (req.query.year && req.query.month){
        // your code for year and month verification
        return res.sendStatus(200)
    }
    return next()
})


module.exports = router
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the query params like so

```
const year = Number(req.query.year);
const month = Number(req.query.month);

if (!isNaN(year) && !isNaN(month)) {
    // check dates and possibly call "next" function to skip
}
```

Comment: No need to use the url package. Checking `req.query.year` and `req.query.month` should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Will update my response.